# Javascript: Zepto swipe left + right, scroll up + down

Tags: javascript, touch, preventdefault, zepto

So I am using the Zepto library to perform some swiping actions over a list of elements that scrolls left and right. The code is pretty simple like so:

```
Zepto('#planlist').swipeRight(function() {
    self.click_left();
});
Zepto('#planlist').swipeLeft(function() {
    self.click_right();
});
```

It just calls the same action as my click button:

```
click_left: function() {
    if(this.position > 0) {
        -- this.position;
        this.animate();
    }
},
click_right: function() {
    if(this.position < this.plans.length - 1) {
        ++ this.position;
        this.animate();
    }
}
```

Anyways. The issue is, unless I set a `preventDefault()` on the scrolling, occasionally a diagonal swipe will both trigger the swipe, and scroll the page. This is a problem, because while the page scroll is happening, it keeps the animation from rendering. However, if I use `preventDefault()`, it keeps the user from being able to scroll up and down when touching this area. This is a problem, because on phone devices, this little area takes up the whole screen, so the user has no ability to scroll the page up and down.

So the question is: Can I make swiping left and right preventDefault and keep the ability to touch-scroll up and down?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: I wasn't able to use Zepto because of this problem, and ended up writing a quick little jquery plugin that allows for it: https://gist.github.com/4111551 - It basically checks both the vertical and horizontal swipe directions, and only swipes if the horizontal distance is larger than the vertical. Feel free to use as-is or base your code off it. Also, play around with the thresholds if the defaults dont work for you. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. But I went with HammerJS instead :)